# Using regular expressions via `re-search-forward` in elisp

Tags: elisp

I want to search for an regular expression with the function `re-search-forward`

When I tried using the examples from the page
here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression#toc1

specifically the regular expression `\w\{20,\}` used to search for a word with 20 letters or more, I get an error.

Here I am placing my cursor after the closing parenthesis in my Lisp buffer and pressing `C-x C-e` for evaluating it.

However, when I use the Regexp I-search via, 
`C-M-s` it highlights the correct word as expected.

Why is this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This regexp:

```
\w\{20,\}
```

is expressed in a double-quoted elisp string like so:

```
"\\w\\{20,\\}"
```

Backslashes are special to the double-quoted read syntax for strings *as well as* being special to regexp syntax; so if a backslash is for the regexp, you need to double it.

Comment: Notice also how, in the screenshots in the question, the incorrect singular backslashes are coloured red?  That is Emacs (26+) telling you that they are probably a mistake.